# Remove 2 categorgies when post status changes from private to publish

Tags: categories

I cannot figure out why this code won't work as an array:

```
function remove2categories( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status == 'private' && $new_status = 'publish' && !in_category(array('3152'), $post ) ) {
        $catsID = array('1186','1208');
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, $catsID, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'remove2categories', 10, 3 );
```

Yet this code works perfectly fine (no array)... only removes 1 out of 2 category ids

```
function remove1categories( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status == 'private' && $new_status = 'publish' && !in_category(array('3152'), $post ) ) {
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, 1186, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'remove1categories', 10, 3 );
```

What am i doing wrong here, how can i get the code to remove both category ID's when post status changes from private to publish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are trying to pass array of string instead of int.

So it search for terms slug with this value instead in terms id.

```
function remove2categories( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status == 'private' && $new_status == 'publish' && !in_category(array(3152), $post ) ) {
        $catsID = array(1186, 1208);
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, $catsID, 'category' );
    }
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'remove2categories', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: You're assigning value to `$new_status` instead of comparing it to value in if condition..

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Yes. I fixed it. didn't noticed that..